# Is there a frontend equivalent for add_menu_page?

Tags: block-editor

I am currently using add_menu_page in my PHP plugin to add a menu item to the main left-hand menu in the WordPress Admin panel.

However; I am wondering if it is possible to achieve the same result with JavaScript using the WordPress React frontend system? This would suit me better as I could add event handlers to the elements on the page and link them with existing frontend (Gutenberg) code.

(I have found the documentation for adding SlotFills - https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/slotfills/ - but this seems to be about panels which appear on the right in the posts / customs posts screens, not for the main menu on the left-hand side).

Thanks

Comment: You can’t add a menu item with React. The admin menu is not a React application. It’s purely PHP.